# In Sqlite3, how to use VACUUM to get more space

Tags: sqlite

I have a database that has been deleting records and adding records all the time.
I only have 2MBytes memory that I can use for this database. I know that I should use VACUUM, but it doesn't work. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: SQLite automatically reuses freed pages. The VACUUM process creates copies of the database file. The answer appears to be "don't".

Answer (score 0):

How did you know it didn't work? 
To verify how big your database is:

```
$sqlite3 test.db              //open the database
$sqlite> PRAGMA page_size;    // request database's page size configure.
1024                          // test.db has page size 1024 bytes.
$sqlite> PRAGMA page_count;   // request database's page count.
677                           // test.db has 677 pages.
```

The size for test.db is 677*677 =  693248 bytes.

To issue "VACUUM", DO NOT ADDING "PRAGMA", it is common mistake, just send "VACUUM" alone:

```
$sqlite> VACUUM;               //re-arrange database
$sqlite> PRAGMA page_count;    //check the new page count  
674                            //after clean up, the page count is reduced
```

Now the database size is: 1024*674= 690176 bytes